# Specific complicated filtering of Pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

The data has many columns but the ones in question are as follows:

```
 MR     Version
GB1       Package
GB5       Package
GB9       3.5
GB5       3.3
GB1       Package
GB9       1.5
GB359     9.1
GB1       Package
GB99      5.5
...
```

MR (model) names are repeating and the `Package` in Version column is also repeating.
I need to first access all rows with Version == `Package`,

- then take their MR model name for instance `GB5`
- then find all other rows with the same MR model name and
- finally check if those other rows (with same MR model name) have a value of Version column different from Package(!= Package).
  Those who have I need to classify as good and those who have not I need to classify as bad.

For instance, from the example data above MR model `GB5` has both a Package and non Package cells hence this model is good, and model GB1 has only Package values in the version column hence it is bad.

For MRs that have only integer values in the Version column such as `GB9` we do not care in this task.

Usually those entries are next to each other and there is two of ever model, usually, so I developed a loop to successfully solve my problem below by selecting every two rows from the dataframe, but now I discovered that in some cases these entries are not next to each other so I need a better solution which escapes me.
In my code below MR is replaced by Author but it does not matter.

```
good_aut = []
bad_aut = []
for i, g in merged_df.groupby(merged_df.index // 2): # takes every two rows
    if g.iloc[0]['Version'] == 'Package':            # if row 1 is a package citation
        if g.iloc[0]['Author'] == g.iloc[1]['Author']: # check if row 1 and 2 authors match
            if g.iloc[1]['Version'] != 'Package':       # finally check if row 2 citation is not package, hence it is GAP citation
                print(g)
                good_aut.append(g.iloc[0]['Author']) # if all conditions are met we add this author to the good list, once for every occurence
            else:
                bad_aut.append(g.iloc[0]['Author'])
        else:
            bad_aut.append(g.iloc[0]['Author'])
```

Comment: You example is not fully clear to me. Is `GB9` good or bad? Also, you did not specify which output you expect. Can you check if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559069/16343464) is what you want?

Comment: Hi and thank you for looking into it. `GB9` is neither good nor bad, I only need models that have `Package` Version cell, so I think option 3 is best. BIG THANK YOU!

Comment: OK, great! If you want to keep only good/bad, you can return `numpy.NaN` instead of `other` in the function and use `dropna()` on the ouput to get rid of the unwanted rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear. Do you expect `Package` to be present in addition to other values?

#### if yes

You can groupby `MR` and check if `Package` is present together with other values:

```
def good_or_bad(s):
    s=set(s)
    if 'Package' in s and len(s.difference(['Package']))>0:
        return 'good'
    return 'bad'
df.groupby('MR')['Version'].apply(good_or_bad)
```

output:

```
MR
GB1       bad
GB359     bad
GB5      good
GB9       bad
GB99      bad
Name: Version, dtype: object
```

#### if no

You can groupby `MR` and check if values other than `Package` are present:

```
(df.groupby('MR')['Version']
 .apply(lambda s: len(set(s).difference(['Package']))>0)
 .map({True: 'good', False: 'bad'})
)
```

output:

```
MR
GB1       bad
GB359    good
GB5      good
GB9      good
GB99     good
Name: Version, dtype: object
```

### I want all three possibilities

```
def good_or_bad(s):
    s=set(s)
    if len(s.difference(['Package']))>0:
        if 'Package' in s:
            return 'good'
        return 'other'
    return 'bad'
df.groupby('MR')['Version'].apply(good_or_bad)
```

output:

```
MR
GB1        bad
GB359    other
GB5       good
GB9      other
GB99     other
Name: Version, dtype: object
```

Comment: Perfect answer covering all possibilities, thank you loads. I need option 3 which covers all possibilities. I think I just need to switch places of `other` and `bad`.

Comment: Sorry @mozway , I just need some clarification of how it works, please.
```python

def good_or_bad(s):
    s=set(s) # what does that do ? :) 
    if len(s.difference(['Package']))>0: # does that check for Package first
        if 'Package' in s:   # does that check for package second time once model having 
                                       package is identified
            return 'good'
        return 'other'
    return 'bad'
df.groupby('MR')['Version'].apply(good_or_bad)
```

Comment: I think I get it, no need to switch it is all correct, just needed to learn about sets.

Comment: Here is the [python documentation on sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and a reference to the [mathematical concept of set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)). Those are powerful to compute union, intersection, exclusion, etc. of groups of elements